Delete links to Bitcoin mixing/laundry sites?
2 questions in particular have an answer by the user @rando:

What Bitcoin Mixing/Laundry Services are availble today?
How can I hide my bitcoin transactions to protect anonymity?

Both answers provide a link that has now been labelled as a scam by other users. The "other users" have no solid reputation rating though, but one semi-believable link was provided as evidence in what was essentially a vandalism answer-edit. I rejected the edit and added a comment with the link, as it was an inappropriate edit.
What I really believe needs to be done though is to remove the links altogether. This would include both the answers from @rando. If there are any other direct links to laundry services, I'd remove those too.
A link to a list of services, in somewhere like the Bitcoin wiki, would be an appropriate answer, with a sensible warning to the users that the services are highly likely to be completely dodgy. 
I'm happy to do some clean up; Would anyone like to comment on my proposed strategy?

Protecting the questions may be sensible too.

Have flagged the offending answers as spam. There was one by a different user too.

Linking to a list of related services sounds like an acceptable solution to me.

Any time any link is known to be spammy/scammy you should flag it for moderator attention. We hate spam quite a lot here and will burninate such links (and often those posting them) with extreme prejudice while shouting some variant of "NOT ON MY WATCH MUTHAF***A!!!"
We should also put some serious thought into whether we should allow questions about mixers at all since their most common use is quite obviously money laundering and we neither a) want to portray Bitcoin in a negative light nor b) want to make recommendations that could be illegal. I think it's defensible since mixers can also simply address anonymity concerns of legitimately obtained funds, which brings it to a question of the image we'd like to portray on this site. Thoughts?

Mixers should be allowed. You can open a separate question to discuss it. Heck, even questions about silk road should be allowed. Knowledge is power, let's not try to bottle it up, but rather spread it.
